# Wrong output in Javascript calling function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to print the result of a JavaScript function, but instead I get the whole function

**Output**

```
x7: function  
function () { return "hello this is form function"; }
```

I want the output:     `hello this is form function`

**HTML**

```
<p id="demo"></p>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var x7 = function (){
   return "hello this is form function";
};
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "x7: " + typeof x7 + "<br>"+x7+"<br>";
```

Comment: Run through your basic JS tutorial again.

Comment: @torazaburo , it was in next chapter now I get it

Comment: function without (), it will return the function definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use parentheses to call your function: `x7()`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

var x7 = function (){
   return "hello this is form function";
};

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =

"x7: " + typeof x7 + "<br>"+
x7()+"<br>";
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're concatenating the function, not the result of a function call. Where you have `+x7+` should be `+x7()+`.

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually calling the function. If you want the output, you should use `x7()`.